Non-type template parameter in struct vs alias
Consider the following snippet (C++20, gcc, clang):
template <class>
struct wrapper;

template <int>
struct backend{};

//(1) OK
template <int Arg>
using my_type = backend<Arg>;

//(2) Doesn't compile
//template <int Arg>
//using my_type = backend<Arg + 1>;

//(3) OK
//template <int Arg>
//struct my_type : backend<Arg + 1>{};

template <int Arg>
struct wrapper<my_type<Arg>> {};

int main() {
  [[maybe_unused]] wrapper<my_type<1>> w;
}

Why doesn't (2) compile but (3) does?

Clang error:  prog.cc:20:12: error: class template partial
specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced;
this partial specialization will never be used
[-Wunusable-partial-specialization]    20 |     struct
wrapper<my_type> {};

I'd appreciate any reference to the Standard.

And you intend for backend  to be incomplete structs?

(2) doesn't work because the compiler isn't going to solve an equation to determine the template parameter of backend. I think it's more interesting how (1) is whitelisted.

Always post complete error along with your question.

@HolyBlackCat as per c++ reference, "a non-type template argument in which a subexpression references a template parameter" is non-deducible.  But then, why does (3) work?  I'm afraid there's some subtle issue related to template aliases behavior.

@user12002570  the snippet is SSCCE, so you can try it with your favorite compiler (the message is compiler-dependent).

@IgorR. Yes, I did try it. But it is the responsibility of the OP to post the error message(at least with one compiler) here on SO so that we don't have to follow any external link. Also, manytimes it happens that a bug is fixed and we no longer get the error message on the said compiler. So if the error is here along  with the code it will make the question complete.

In (2), you could omit the using and spell the specialization as template <int Arg> struct wrapper<backend<Arg + 1>> {}; (which is also invalid, the compiler isn't going to solve equations like X = Arg + 1; X = 1). In (3), the base class is a red herring, it doesn't affect anything.

Yes, the base class in (3) is not a subexpression.

I can easily answer this eithout quoting the standard.  Decoding where the standard lets (1) work is the tricky part, I forget...

Matching partial specializations relies on template argument deduction and alias templates are never deduced. They are expanded eagerly before deduction.
See [temp.alias/2]:

When a template-id refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by substitution of its template-arguments for the template-parameters in the defining-type-id of the alias template.
[Note 1: An alias template name is never deduced. — end note]

Example 1 (OK):
template <class>
struct wrapper;

template <int>
struct backend{};

template <int Arg>
using my_type = backend<Arg>;

template <int Arg>
struct wrapper<my_type<Arg>> {};
// --> equivalent to:
// struct wrapper<backend<Arg>>

int main() {
  [[maybe_unused]] wrapper<my_type<1>> w;
  // --> equivalent to:
  // [[maybe_unused]] wrapper<backend<1>> w;
}

Deduction compares wrapper<backend<1>> to wrapper<backend<Arg>>. In the context of this deduction, Arg is deducible to 1.
Example 2 (BAD):
template <class>
struct wrapper;

template <int Arg>
using my_type = backend<Arg + 1>;

template <int Arg>
struct wrapper<my_type<Arg>> {};
// --> equivalent to:
// struct wrapper<backend<Arg + 1>>

int main() {
  [[maybe_unused]] wrapper<my_type<1>> w;
  // --> equivalent to:
  // [[maybe_unused]] wrapper<backend<2>> w;
}

Deduction compares wrapper<backend<2>> to wrapper<backend<Arg + 1>>. In the context of this deduction, Arg is not deducible.
This is because of [temp.deduct.type/5.4]:

(Non-deduced contexts include:) A non-type template argument or an array bound in which a subexpression references a template parameter.

Example 3 (OK):
template <class>
struct wrapper;

template <int>
struct backend{};

template <int Arg>
struct my_type : backend<Arg + 1>{};

template <int Arg>
struct wrapper<my_type<Arg>> {};

int main() {
  [[maybe_unused]] wrapper<my_type<1>> w;
}

Deduction compares wrapper<my_type<1>> to wrapper<my_type<Arg>>. In the context of this deduction, Arg is deducible to 1.

IIUC, "alias templates are never deduced" and "non-template argument in subexpression" are 2 separate issues.  I'm not sure where in the answer you used the fact that "alias templates are never deduced", could you please clarify that?

The "alias templates are never deduced" text, which means more precisely (see the quote) that alias templates are eagerly expanded before deduction and partial specialization matching... That means in every case, alias templates are expanded as the first step. The "non-template argument in subexpression" explains why, after expanding alias templates, deduction and thus matching fails in this example.
